# Is it possible to change the color of a floating action button every time it is clicked?

Tags: android

I have a FAB which its default color is green, is it possible to change the color every time I click it? For exemple, from green to red.

If it's possible I suppose I'll need to add a custom color in color/custom_color.xml, but what are the attributes?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: @Maxouille I made a custom xml file in my res/color/ folder but I don't know the attribute to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `app:backgroundTint` to your `FloatingActionButton` in xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/red"/>
```

And in your activity change button color by adding click listener:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.blue)));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setBackgroundTintList()` to update the color of your fab button.

```
 fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
                    .parseColor("#33691E")));
```

Then, you just have to set an OnclickListener and pick a random color in an array of values.

```
// Create list of random colors
ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add("#33691E");
colors.add("#00AE1E");
colors.add("#45F41E");
//Srt onclicklistener
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Pick random color
                Random r = new Random();
                int randomIdx = r.nextInt(colors.size());
                // Set background
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
                    .parseColor(colors.get(randomIdx))));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of Floating Action button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
     app:borderWidth="0dp"
     app:elevation="2dp"
     app:fabSize="normal" >
```

so  `app:backgroundTint` is the attribute with which you can change background color of FAB.

or if you want to change icon color:

```
android:tint="@color/red"
```